# Show new attribute in product view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute, product-view

I have a new attribute 'delivered_in' and I'd like to add it to the product page in Magento. I have edited the view.phtml and added the following code:

```
    <div><p><?php $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('delivered_in')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?></p></div>
```

When I go to the product page I can see the div and p tags are there but the attribute in between doesn't seem to be called (even though it exists within the product).

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `echo` before the statement. Besides, it can be simplified to:

```
<div><p><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('delivered_in') ?></p></div>
```

Comment: Hello this solution worked for me. Thank you very much, apologies for the late response guys. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If it worked for you, please accept the answer, so that it does not count as unanswered anymore for the site statistics (important to get out of beta eventually). http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Is  "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" set this option to YES ? This option has to be set as yes while creating custom attribute ?

Comment: Yes it is marked a visitble on product view page on front-end.

Comment: did you tried any other solution mentioned below ?

Comment: Yes this one worked thanks <div><p><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('delivered_in') ?></p></div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php $product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), 'delivered_in', Mage::app()->getStore());?>
```

We can get any attribute value by this code.

Source : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379792/magento-get-a-custom-attribute-value-without-loading-the-entire-product)

Answer (score 0):

Or i'm pretty sure if you have it set to visible on frontend you can use camel case function to get it as:

```
<div><p><?php echo $_product->getDeliveredIn() ?></p></div>
```